# Subtrair 2 semanas de uma data completa em pyhton

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou pensando um data nesse formato:

```
time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") // 00/00/0000
```

Quero subtrair duas semanas dessa data, mas não sei como fazer.

Answer (score 7):

Pode usar o [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#timedelta-objects) e passar como parâmetro a quantidade de dias que quer substituir de uma data.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

hoje = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=14)
```