# Timestamp no Django (Referencia)

Tags: python, django, strtotime

Eu preciso disso:

`strtotime('+10 days');` = *PHP*

no Django eu tentei:

```
import time

struct_time = time.strptime("+10 days")
print "returned tuple: %s " % struct_time
```

Bom, em toda documentação não diz como fazer da forma que eu quero, com tudo, me interessei em estudar manipulação de *time* no `python`

mas, como eu faço isso `strtotime('+10 days')` no `python`?

Seguindo o link do comentário do nosso amigo @hkotsubo

Eu tentei para adicionar 10 dias:

```
datetime.today() - timedelta(days=10)
```

e para minutos:

```
datetime.today() - timedelta(minutes=30)
```

Claro que tambem importei:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Comment: Tentou usar `timedelta`? -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178846/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu tentei, mas não entendi muito bem, só preciso adicionar 10 dias contando com o dia de hoje, e utilizando esse mesmo conceito, adicionar 30 minutos

Comment: Vc viu o [link que passei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/178846/112052)? Basta adaptar o código que tem lá: `data = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=10)`. Se quiser 30 minutos, use `timedelta(minutes=30)`

Comment: Deu certo aqui @hkotsubo, isso seria uma duplicata né?

Comment: `datetime.today() - timedelta(days=10)` está subtraindo 10 dias, basta trocar o `-` para `+` :-)

Comment: Sim, se a resposta da outra pergunta também resolve o seu caso, então é duplicata..